# d3.js object not completely displaying withing a card

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, d3.js, svg

I am new to d3 and currently following a tutorial from FreeCodeCamp.

Essentially I want to render some circles into a bootstrap Card however it appears to fall off the card on the left and also cutting off on the right.

```
import { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import * as d3 from "d3";

class Process extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.createProcess = this.createProcess.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.createProcess();
    this.drawProcess();
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.drawProcess();
  }

  drawProcess() {
    const width = +this.svg.attr("width");
    const height = +this.svg.attr("height");

    const makeFruit = test => {
      return test;
    };

    const fruits = d3.range(10).map(() => makeFruit("apple"));

    this.svg
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(fruits)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", (d, i) => i * 120 + 60)
      .attr("fill", "orange")
      .attr("cy", height / 2)
      .attr("r", 50);

    fruits.pop();
    this.svg
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data("fruits")
      .exit()
      .remove();
  }

  createProcess() {
    this.svg = d3
      .selectAll("#flowView")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", "100%");
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
export default Process;
```

Thanks in Advance[image: see attached image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to `translate` the circles. Add this line to the `circles`.

```
.attr("transform", "translate(0,75)")
```

This will translate circles `75px` down.

```
this.svg
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(fruits)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", (d, i) => i * 120 + 60)
  .attr("fill", "orange")
  .attr("cy", height / 2)
  .attr("r", 50)
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,75)");
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. It did move the circles down however there is only 2.5 circles showing when there should be 10 circles.

Comment: @EdwardHang Probably your `svg` is not wide enough. Try increasing width of your `svg` in `createProcess`. Namely,  `attr("width", 600);`

Comment: Thanks. That would certainly fix it. If there were more circles for example, how can I keep the circles inside the card box? It appears the circles would overflow or unaware of the underlining card box

Comment: @EdwardHang You might want to check out `flex-wrap` property, or `overflow: auto`. It is better to ask a different question for it, you get more detailed answers.

Comment: Will do. Thanks again